# Report Viewer in VS 2013 gives error when added to Asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, reportviewer

I was creating a `ReportViewer` in Asp.net application. I used [this tutorial](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Report-Viewer-control-Tutorial-with-example.aspx) for creating the `ReportViewer`.

When I added the ReportViewer in the page, I'm getting an error as shown below,

```
The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace     
'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I can't find the reference in `ReferenceManager`.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388274/visual-studio-2013-report-viewer-the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target-n) with solution, but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a reference to Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms in your Project within references, and then re-build your Solution

This may help [Why can't I see Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms version 10.0.0.0 in "Add Reference..." dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396146/why-cant-i-see-microsoft-reportviewer-webforms-version-10-0-0-0-in-add-referen)

Comment: I have mentioned earlier that i cant find reference in reference manager

Comment: Thank you!!. Reportviewer tool is present and not the reference, Why is that?